# Datastax OpsCenter OpenSource not showing "data size" in ring or list view

Tags: datastax, opscenter

Using OpsCenter OpenSource version 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I cannot see the "Data Size" Metric in Node Ring or List view however, if I click on a single node I can see it's disk usage. I'm not having any luck getting information from datastax agent logs or from opscenterd logs.

I suspect that perhaps this is an enterprise only feature?

Can provide additional information as requested.

Screenshots for clarity can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRrio.jpg). (sorry, I need more "reputation" to post them directly to this thread)

Comment: Given you some repu. Now ya can upload screenshots 

Comment: Its not an enterprise feature. What version of C* are you using? OpsCenter 5.2.1 doesn't support C* 2.2, so if using that its probably having issues collecting the metrics.

Comment: Ah, yup I'm using C* 2.2. Thanks!

(Thanks for the rep too alexandresaiz!)

Answer (score 2):

OpsCenter doesn't have full C* 2.2 support. I am, unfortunately using C* 2.2.